# How to store excel data from a sharepoint path to sql server using ssis package

Tags: .net, sql-server, ssis, msbi

I am creating a SSIS Package for importing excel file(with Several tables in the form of named ranges) from sharepoint to sql server(database) tables.

I tried importing file to a local folder using script task and then storing it as a excel source and exporting the data to oledb destination.

The Problem is that the destination tables have foreign key constraint set. and There are few columns such as created day and updated day which use the datetime data type,and these values are not present in the excel source.

How can i perform a transformation for adding these data while fetching the data from excel source to the oledb destination.

Your suggestions can be a valuable source. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Decompose your problem into smaller units. Continue doing so until you have a unit you are able to solve. Then composite your solutions together until you've solved the problem at hand.

Comment: Your current question is far too broad, far too much question and not enough demonstrated effort. Do you *really* need every step of your question solved or is there a particular step that is vexing you? If so, what implementation have you attempted and what was the consequence of doing it? If you're encountering errors, what are all the specific messages being reported back. Click the Edit button above and patch that into the body of the question.